# androidstudio2 variant multiple apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'd like to have multiple apk files based on the same source so I can have a working and development version on my device.  I thought that build variants and flavors would give me this but what I'm seeing is that when I select one variant the apk file for the other is replaced.  I've added this to the app build.gradle file and my build variant window allows me to select phoneDebug or tabletDebug.

```
productFlavors {
    phone {
        applicationId "com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.phone"
        versionName "1.0-phone"
    }
    tablet {
        applicationId "com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.tablet"
        versionName "1.0-tablet"
    }
}
```

I created directories under the app/src called tablet/res/values and phone/res/values and have different strings.xml files in each and my layout xml file references the string hello_world which is different in each string file.  All of this is working: when I select the phoneDebug or the tabletDebug variants I get the appropriate hello string.
I see app-tablet-debug-unaligned.apk or app-phone-debug-unaligned.apk in the build directory depending on what variant I have selected.  But when I select the one variant the other disappears.
When I run one variant that apk appearantly is installed over the other -- at least there is only one BuildDemo installed in the apps on my device.
How can I get separate phoneDebug and tabletDebug apks installed on my device?
Thanks.
Steve S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question to make the answer stand out a bit more in hopes this will help someone else.

The two apps already have different applicationId's from the productFlavors entry.  And with gradle -- I'm skeptical about changing the manifest file to change my output.  It might work but I was bitten several times doing that while moving from Eclipse to AndroidStudio.
It turned out that my assumption that the apk was getting over-written was wrong.  When I looked at the apps using Settings->Device->Apps there were two instances of BuildDemo.  The launcher was showing only one instance.  Also using "adb 'pm list packages -f builddemo'" gives:

```
package:/data/app/com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.phone-1.apk=com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.phone
package:/data/app/com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.tablet-1.apk=com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.tablet
```

My fix was to override the app_name (which is referenced in the manifest file to set the application label) in the strings.xml file for each variant.  The one under the phone/res/values/strings.xml is now BuildDemo.phone and the one under the tablet... directory is BuildDemo.tablet.  Now when I open the launcher I see BuildDemo.phone and BuildDemo.tablet.
As always, thanks for the suggestions.  They pointed me towards an answer.
Steve S.

Answer (score 1):

To get different variants or flavors to produce separate apps (as seen by the Android OS) you'll need different applicationIds.  You've got the right idea with different ones for phone and tablet.  A step further would be to add different suffixes per the build variant (e.g. Debug)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

This then produces "com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.phone" and "com.ebookfrenzy.builddemo.app.phone.debug" for Release and Debug builds respectively for your "phone" flavor

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the defined package name from AndroidManifest.xml and for AndroidStudio the build.prop (Module app) to identify if its the same app.
If you want to have "the same" app twice installed, the only way would be the change the package name. Then Android thinks its a different app, otherwise Android will always override it like you have described

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to define a different `applicationId` in gradle build flavors.
[Here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) is the way, how to do this.

In my opinion it would be better to keep the same applicationId as a gradle variable and concatenate it with applicationId suffix. That way, the Id's would be different only by suffix.